# How do I remove an app folder is OSX when all else fails?

Tags: macos, hfs

I have a folder/package in the Applications called CrashPlan.app. The uninstall failed and I am left with a folder that has a Contents folder, but aside from that, is completely empty.

The folder info: drwxrwxr-x@  3 root         102 13 Jul 20:36 CrashPlan.app

I have tried the following:
sudo rm -rf CrashPlah.app
chown
chflags nouchg

I tried the same things in Safe Mode and Recovery Mode.
I tried disabling System Integrity Protection.
Whenever I try to remove the folder I get:
rm: CrashPlan.app/Contents: Operation not permitted
rm: CrashPlan.app: Operation not permitted

Does anyone have any advise? I feel like I've tried everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When CrashPlan uninstall fails, [one solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/121628) is to reinstall CrashPlan and follow the steps in [this support article](https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Getting_Started/Uninstalling_The_Code42_CrashPlan_App).

Because uninstall has already failed, the problem may be that the "system immutable flag" is set for /Applications/CrashPlan.app or its contents. In Terminal, try `ls -ldO /Applications/CrashPlan.app` and `ls -ldO /Applications/CrashPlan.app/Contents`. The `ls` command may show something like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x@  3 root  102  schg   13 Jul 14 20:36 CrashPlan.app
```

If you see the schg flag, run these commands.

```
sudo chflags -R noschg /Applications/CrashPlan.app
sudo rm -fR /Applications/CrashPlan.app
```

If `chflags` fails, the flag may be unset only when the system is in single-user mode.

If `rm` still causes the "Operation not permitted" error, CrashPlan.app may be locked in Finder. If it is locked, trash /Applications/CrashPlan.app. If Finder asks about moving locked items to the trash, click `continue`. Empty trash and when Finder asks about removing locked items, click `Remove All Items`.

To completely remove CrashPlan, remove these folders if they exist.

- /Library/Application Support/CrashPlan
- ~/Library/Application Support/CrashPlan

There may also be `com.code42` files in these folders that were not removed.

- /Library/LaunchAgents
- /Library/LaunchDaemons
- ~/Library/LaunchAgents

Answer (score 0):

For those who find this, here's a link to download a current version of the CrashPlan Home app, install it, then run the installer to remove the application without TOO much headache.

https://www.code42.com/crashplan/download/